# Batch generating *.mbtiles using Qtile in qGIS

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, pyqgis

I've been able to use the Qtiles plug in to generate an *.mbtiles raster for a shapefile, which is great.
Now I want to make *.mbtiles for a whole directory of shapefiles (1000+).
My thinking was to write a script in the qGIS tools area, but I don't know how to call a plug-in via a script in qGIS.

Does any one know how I can call a plug in a script, or how to set up a batch process for making *.mbtiles from a TMS service?

[image]